# What means "Generic type 'Feature<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)" in Typescript?

Tags: generics, typescript, geojson

I try to use GeoJson in typescript but the compiler throws error for this two variables: `Generic type 'Feature<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)`

```
  const pos = <GeoJSON.Feature>{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [0, 1]
    }
  };

  const oldPos = <GeoJSON.Feature>{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [2, 4]
    }
  };
```

What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Try <GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Point>>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Feature interface requires a parameter:

```
export interface Feature<T extends GeometryObject> extends GeoJsonObject
{
    geometry: T;
    properties: any;
    id?: string;
}
```

Try this:

```
  const pos = <GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.GeometryObject>>{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties":{},
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [0, 1]
    }
  };
```

And maybe introduce a helper type and set the type on pos instead of casting will help you ensure you've set the required 'properties' attribute:

```
type GeoGeom = GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.GeometryObject>;
const pos: GeoGeom = {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: "foo",
    geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [0, 1]
    }
};
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but yes indeed it work. Could you plz add "properties":{} in the code block after "Try this". It is not valid this way, missing "properties" property. Thx you !